# TextInputLayout set color of startIconDrawable programmaticaly

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, material-components

I want to set start icon for my `TextInputLayout` programmatically, but I faced problem with his color. When I set drawable, its color becomes gray, but original color of it is orange. I know that I can change its color by using `startIconTint` parameter in xml, but I want to change its color programmatically. Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the methods [**`setStartIconDrawable`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#setstarticondrawable_1) and [**`setStartIconTintList`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#setstarticontintlist):

```
textInputLayout.setStartIconDrawable(...);
textInputLayout.setStartIconTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this,R.color.text_input_selector));
```

You can use a color or a color selector.
Something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_activated="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.54" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Can you explain how to work with `setStartIconTintList()`

Comment: @AssetBekbossynov This method applies a tint to the start icon drawable as the `app:startIconTint` in the xml or `<item name="startIconTint">....</item>` in the style. You can use a single color or you can use a `ColorStateList` to define different colors in the different states.

Comment: Thank you, for answer. I solved it using `valueOf(color: Int)` method of `ColorStateList`. Final version looks like that `textInputLayout.setStartIconTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(resources.getColor(R.color.color_name)));`